What is a fast and statistically powerful way of heuristically removing duplicates from a set of (unordered) sets?
I have an application where I (heuristically) create a large set of test candidates, which are themselves large sets of elements in no particular order. In order to not use the same test candidate twice, I want to remove duplicates from this set. In the worst case this means I need to sort all the arrays and then compare n elements in each of m sets, giving me a quadratic complexity.

Example: I have the set {{0,1}, {2,5,8}, {1,9}, {5,8,2}, {9,1}} and I
want to reduce it to {{0,1}, {2,5,8}, {1,9}}

Since I work heuristically anyway, I do not care too much if I accidentally delete a few test candidates which haven't been duplicates. So what I do now is the following:

Create an ID for each candidate {x_0, ..., x_n} by using a hash function and applying xor, that is by computing hash(x_0) ^ ... ^ hash(x_n)
Store the IDs in a set and delete a candidate if the ID is already present.

If I understand the math correctly, this should give me a 1/(2^k) chance that two non-equal sets have the same id, where k is the size of the hash type.
So my questions are:

Is my math correct here?
Is there merit in instead using another commutative operation, such as a sum or is it the same?
Is there a better way to handle this in n+m?


Why not simply make M buckets, then loop through all the integers from 1 to N and put each one into a random bucket?

This is a good approach in general, although you might find that your xor hash function isn't a particularly good choice. It's fast, sure, but it's not a particularly good hash function. You'll likely end up with a large number of hash collisions. You might want to consider a better hash function, although that will probably require sorting the elements in each set.

@virchau You don't want to put a set in a random bucket because you want sets that contain the same numbers to end up in the same bucket. A hash function is essentially assigning a bucket based on the contents of the set.

@JimMischel Thank you for the answer. Do you have a suggestion for a better function to combine the IDs? Sorting the individual sets isn't too much of an issue (although I found it to be elegant not having to do this), I primarily want to avoid the quadratic complexity.
And could you give insight why xor wouldn't be good if I expect the hashes to be uniformly distributed?

XOR doesn't produce a uniform distribution. For example, the set {3,7,9} cannot with XOR alone hash to any value greater than 15 because only 4 bits are set. A good hash function will distribute values throughout the range of output, regardless of the range of the input values. I'd suggest some kind of multiplicative hashing. The one in the Wikipedia article will give you a much better distribution than your XOR version. The entire article is worth reading.

Another idea would be to try combining/chaining different types of hashes and observing how well they work. For example, you could keep your xor idea, then apply another hash (for example adding all elements in a set), then letting the xor and sum pair be considered the hash for a set. You could also try looking at bloom filters too if allowing for a small margin of error.
